# Как написать на своей странице фильтр, схожий с фильтром Django в админке?

Tags: django

Здравствуйте уважаемые гуру сообщества.
Я новичек в Django и мои знания пока ограничены.
Читал документацию, может я слепой, но там описан процесс создания фильтра, который пересылает на другую страницу. Путем именованных url `<int:pk>` или `<slug:slug>`.
Но мне нужен фильтр, который будет работать только на одной странице
Как написать такой фильтр? Чтобы при нажатии на поле выводились все данные связанные с этим полем.

Хотя бы оставьте ссылки на подробный источник по данной теме.
Благодарю добрые люди.

Answer (score 0):

Настоятельно рекомендую обратить внимание на уже готовое решение, чтобы не городить свой велосипед.
https://pypi.org/project/django-filter/